# Sending email attachments hosted in S3 via Nodemailer using ReadableStreams

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, nodemailer

I'm trying to send emails with Nodemailer containing attachments hosted in S3, using JS AWS SDK v3. The Nodemailer docs show an example of sending an attachment using a read stream generated from reading a file:

```
{   // stream as an attachment
    filename: 'text4.txt',
    content: fs.createReadStream('file.txt')
},
```

I can create a `ReadableStream` for my attachment in S3 like so:

```
const s3Stream = await s3Client
    .send(/* ... */)
    .then((response) => {
        // ...
        return response.Body.transformToWebStream() // returns Promise<ReadableStream>
    })
    .catch(/* ... */)
```

If I attempt to pass `s3Stream` directly into the `content` field for my Nodemailer attachment, I get an error: `Type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to type 'string | Readable | Buffer | undefined`.

The `Readable` class has a static method `fromWeb`. Calling `Readable.fromWeb(s3Stream)` gives the following:

```
Argument of type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadableStream<any>'.
  Type 'ReadableStream' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream<any>': locked, cancel, getReader, pipeThrough, and 4 more.
```

`Readable` objects have a method `wrap`:

```
new Readable().wrap(s3Stream)
```

Trying this results in the following error:

```
Argument of type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NodeJS.ReadableStream'.
  Type 'ReadableStream' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream': readable, read, setEncoding, pause, and 22 more.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known problem with S3 SDK (check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4720)), it shows `response.Body` as a union of typings for both browsers (`ReadableStream`) and node.js (`Readable`), while at the runtime returning a determined type of value depending on the platform you run it on.

So if you are sure that your code will only work in node.js you just do type casting:

```
import { Readable } from 'node:stream';

(res.Body as Readable)?.pipe(...);
```

Or even better add a type guard just to be sure:

```
import { Readable } from 'node:stream';

if(isReadable(res.Body)) {
    res.Body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./file2.txt'));
} else {
    throw new TypeError('res.Body is not a readable stream');
}

function isReadable(value: unknown): value is Readable {
  return value instanceof Readable
}
```